# How to get Key/Value Pairs From json Response in Angular 2 in the component.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

NOTE : I do not need a solution to iterate over the json data in HTML template. There I am able to do via *ngFor. i want to do it in component.ts where i am actually getting the response.

I have a service in propload.service.ts which gives the list of key and value pairs from a property file.

```
 `getData(): Observable<Object[]> {
 return this.http.get(this.dummyDataUrl)
 .map((response:Response)=>response.json())
 .catch(this.handleError);
 }`
```

I am calling this service as below in my demo.component.ts file

```
 `ngOnInit():void
 {
 this.dummyService.getData().subscribe(response=>  {
 console.log(response)
 });
 }`
```

Here I am able to log the complete json response object as a whole in console which i can see using the developer option in chrome. If i expand that object then i get the key value pairs that came from the properties file. Till this much it works fine.

I am unable to access the key value pairs from the response object in same place that is in the second code snippet, right below the console.log(), I want to be able to have some for loop or some other way so that i can get the key value pairs individually.

The end task is to be able to store these data in session storage of the browser. I already have the way to do so, but for that i need individual key and value pair to be able to perform some modification in between and then log the same in session storage.

I tried some inbuilt methods like response.keys which should return list of all the keys, but still in the console if i try to log that, i am getting undefined everytime.

Can any one suggest as to how can i get the results ?

A big thanks for the same.

Comment: Like Meir says below, Use Object.keys(response), not response.keys.

Answer (score 6):

Use `Object.keys(response)` to get an array with all the keys

Comment: Hi Meir. Thanks a lot. Just what i needed.